# Switching a relay through a wireless connection

Tags: microcontroller, pic, relay, spi, transceiver

I want to create a circuit which will wirelessly drive a relay. I only have a little experience with Arduino. I know what peripherals I need, but I don't know what micro-controller to use. I made a list and I need to know if the components will work all together with the microchip PIC18F26K80 microcontroller, or if you have any other (cheap) suggestion.

- a relay like [that](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xrelay%2030a%20ARDUINO&_nkw=relay%2030a%20ARDUINO&_sacat=0&_from=R40)
- the uln2003 to drive the relay from the microcontroller
- a Wireless RF Transceiver(10 pin) 915mhz
- a programmer like [that](http://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-PIC-Programming-Develop-Microcontroller-Programmer-K150-ICSP-New-/181456859331?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item2a3fabf0c3)
- ethernet magjack (to be able to send and receive tcp/udp packets)

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please use a more descriptive title next time and the "I" when you are referring to yourself is always capitalized in English.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I will try to by more descriptive next time.

Comment: Why specifically a 10 pin wireless transceiver - that seems OCD?

Comment: Because every wireless transceiver at 915mhz that I found has 10 pins and i dont know if have to use all of them

Comment: Why do you need an ethernet port if you're running this wirelessly?
Might be easier if you're starting out to go for the arduino and shield route

Comment: I already own an arduino yun, I want to know how to build my own circuits and for my project I need wireless and ethernet communication.

Comment: I was googling and found that every microcontroller that has ISP interface can be conected to ENC28J60 ethernet module. If this is true, then I dont need the microcontroller to have intergrated ethernet, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use a much cheaper PIC, like the 16F88. RF transceivers are not "that" easy to use, you could try the HC-05 bluetooth modules : they're simple "transparent" bridge, and you communicate with them through a UART (16F88 has 1 UART, and it's real easy to set up) and Arduino has one too.

You should consider buying a microchip PicKit3 instead of a cheap eBay icsp programmer. PicKit's firmware is regularly updated and programs virtually any PIC.